# What is faster? Running an empty function or checking if function is undefined?

Tags: javascript, performance, function, optimization, undefined

I was writing some code where a function being passed in as an argument might sometimes be undefined. Being curious about this as bad 'practice', I wondered what is actually faster? Giving an empty function, or having the function check if the argument was undefined?

I did the following test to try. The answer was very surprising!

```
var timesTest = 1000;

function empty(){}
console.time('running an empty function');
for( var i=0; i<timesTest; i++ ){
  empty();
}
console.timeEnd('running an empty function');

var somethingthatdoesnotexist;
console.time('checking if a function exists');
for( var i=0; i<timesTest; i++ ){
  if( somethingthatdoesnotexist ){
    somethingthatdoesnotexist();
  }
}
console.timeEnd('checking if a function exists');

// results:
// running an empty function: 0.103ms
// checking if a function exists: 0.036ms
```

At low numbers, checking for undefined argument is much faster.

Things get interesting once the times tested increases.

```
// var timesTest = 100000;
// results:
// running an empty function: 1.125ms
// checking if a function exists: 1.276ms
```

and

```
// results:
// var timesTest = 1000000000;
// running an empty function: 2096.941ms
// checking if a function exists: 2452.922ms
```

As the number of tests grew, running a blank function becomes a bit faster by a margin.

I haven't tried plotting this out on a graph yet, but I'm curious as to this behavior. Does anyone know why this is? How does this affect things in real world code?

Comment: "what is actually faster" --- neither. Prefer what is maintainable better.

Comment: For your tests to measure something meaningful - you should both try to run existing and not existing functions. And pick one randomly

Answer (score 20):

1. http://jsperf.com for more accurate benchmarking and fancy graphs. I made one: http://jsperf.com/empty-vs-check
2. This is micro-optimization. **NOBODY WILL EVER NOTICE A DIFFERENCE.** There's a difference of less than a half a second for a billion iterations, which will never happen. Do what you think is more readable; don't worry about performance.

Comment: While this is definitely the correct answer on what to do, I must admit being slightly curious on the why side. One thing I can think of is if the function is being inlined (i.e. function invocation being replaced with nothing) as the compiler detects the large loop, while the variable test needs to be done each time, but it's just an empty hypothesis. It is also, I suspect, highly sensitive on what it is run on (V8 being a proper optimising compiler should handle things a bit differently from JIT like IonMonkey, for example. I'm looking forward to jsPerf results once it gathers more data.)

Comment: I think it would be more correct to add the 4th case: http://jsperf.com/empty-vs-check/2 It would be the worst case in comparison to calling an empty function

Comment: Thank you for the link to jsperf and advice. I think you're missing the point though, you're absolutely right this is a micro-optimization, and the question may have sounded like I'm asking which one to use, which was not was I was asking. I merely wanted to sate my curiosity, which I certainly hope is ok here.